# ggplot2 Error: object 'ratio' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found a code on the web that must (will) produce a graphics representing some data from the U.S. Department of Labor: Bureau of Labor Statistics.:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("unemp.csv", colClasses = c("Date", "numeric")))
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=ratio))
p + geom_point() + geom_smooth() + xlab("Year") + 
ylab("Civilian Employment Population Ratio (%)") + 
labs(title="Bureau of Labor Statistics Series EMRATIO 
            (seasonally adjusted) to 2012-10-01")
```

but it do not working and produces this error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ratio' not found
```

What is missing in this code?

'unemp.csv' contain data from [here](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/EMRATIO.txt) and resulting graphics must looking like [this](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-138609a199fdeae521241db869a38850).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error appeared because there weren't any variables named "date" and "ratio". This works fine:

```
 library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(read.table("unemp.txt", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("Date", "numeric")))
names(df) <- c("date", "ratio")
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=ratio))
p + geom_point() + geom_smooth() + xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("Civilian Employment Population Ratio (%)") +
  labs(title="Bureau of Labor Statistics Series EMRATIO (seasonally adjusted) to 2012-10-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201906/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-kernel-density-estimate-at-specific-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201906/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-kernel-density-estimate-at-specific-points/%22this%22) may be useful for any one else looking around for heatmapping.