# Use `fields::interp.surface` to interpolate from grid to irregular points

Tags: r

I'm trying to do bilinear interpolation from a grid to a set of irregular points, same as [How can I get the value of a kernel density estimate at specific points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201906/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-kernel-density-estimate-at-specific-points). However, when I try the accepted answer there I get a dimension mismatch error:

```
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 3 + 2* x * rexp(n) + rnorm(n)
# add some outliers
y[sample(1:n,20)] <- rnorm(20,20,20)
DF <- data.frame(x,y)

# Calculate 2d density over a grid
library(MASS)
dens <- kde2d(x,y)

# create a new data frame of that 2d density grid
# (needs checking that I haven't stuffed up the order here of z?)
gr <- data.frame(with(dens, expand.grid(x,y)), as.vector(dens$z))
names(gr) <- c("x", "y", "z")
newdata=data.frame(xgr=x, ygr=y)
dens <- fields::interp.surface(gr, newdata)

# the interp.surface output is 2x as long as dim(newdata)[1]
length(dens)
dim(newdata)[1]
```

Any help appreciated, and apologies if this is trivial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create the `gr` object. Just pass `dens` directly to `interp.surface`:

```
newdata=data.frame(x=x, y=y)
newdata$z <- fields::interp.surface(dens, newdata)
```